# Get FusionTable tableId knowing the name in Java Android API

Tags: java, android, optimization, google-api, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to get content of fusion-table knowing the name of the table.
I'm using the Java Google API libraries in Android code.
Actually i use this code:

```
String table_name = "table";
TableList tablelist = client.table().list().execute();
if (tablelist.getItems()!=null){
   for (Table table : tablelist.getItems()) {
           if (table.getName().equals(table_name)){
         `     String fusionId = table.getTableId();
           }
       }
}
```

Cause itself it's in a circle it seems to me heavy... i prefer to get TableId with a "row script" knowing the name.

Any solution?

Comment: In case you weren't aware - you can get the ID of any table from the fusion table web interface.  Just look at File menu --> 'about this table'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Drive API to locate a Fusion Table by name

Make a call to Files: list with q=title contains 'table_name' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.fusiontable'

This will return a file list containing a file descriptor for your table if one exists with that name. The file id is also the table id.